# Mostrar tablas de mysql en html con php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy intentando mostrar una tabla de `phpmyadmin mysql` en una pagina web con `html` y `php`, les adjunto el código

```
    <?php
$conexion=mysqli_connect('localhost','root',''.'gdl');
?>

    <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Producto</td>
        <td>Cantidad</td>
        <td>Tipo</td>
    </tr>
        <?php
        $sql="SELECT * from productos";
        $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
        while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar['producto'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar['cantidad'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar['tipo'] ?></td>
    </tr>
        <?php
        }?>
    </table>
```

de ante mano muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: `$conexion=mysqli_connect('localhost','root',''.'gdl');` aquí hay un error, pusiste punto **(.)** en vez de coma **(,)**, qué error te muestra en la página?

Comment: Gracias, no habia notado ese error. La pagina web no me muestra ningun error, solamente muestra la tabla con las divisiones de Producto, Cantidad y Tipo pero sin ningun valor

Comment: En `$result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);` coloca lo siguiente  `or die('La consulta salió mal');`, de esta forma: `$result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql) or die('La consulta salió mal');` si hubiese algún error en la consulta te mandaría ese mensaje, seguro que así se llaman los campos de tu tabla _productos_ y seguro que si tienes datos en tu tabla?

Comment: Agregué el código que me diste y la página sigue igual, no manda el error. Y sobre las columnas de la tabla, si así se llaman las columnas y cada una tiene 4 datos

Comment: Ya iniciaste el modulo de `apache` y de `MySQL` en xampp?

Comment: Afirmativo ambos servicios estan en linea

Comment: Pues ya te comenté todo lo que se me ocurre, porque es raro que no te salga ningún error y no veo error en tu código, por último aplica un `var_dump()` a `$result`, así `sql="SELECT * from productos";
        $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
var_dump($result);` y dime que te muestra.

Comment: Aplique el codigo que me dijiste y sigue sin mostrar nada, la pagina web sigue igual a pesar de que le doy f5, incluso la cerre y volvi a abrir, te adjunto todo el codigo de la pagina

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=122-GFG6LcD6kDzW2YfzL-YNT0Gjnu0_v

Comment: Pues en realidad no veo otro error y no sé que pueda ser porque ni siquiera te manda un warning en caso de que estuviera fallando la conexión o la consulta, ya no se me ocurre nada compañero. :S

Comment: De igual manera agradezco infinitamente tu apoyo compan;ero, seguire buscando otras maneras, gracias!.

Answer (score 0):

te dejo un ejemplo espero y te fuincione

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example" >
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>PRODUCTO</th>
                            <th>CANTIDAD</th>
                            <th>TIPO</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
<?php
if($_COOKIE["lvl"]==1){
    $result=query("SELECT ");
}else{
    $result=query("SELECT ");
}
$item="";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
if($row["idProducto"]<>'' and $row["idCantidad"]<>'')
{
    $item=$row["idProducto"] . " - " . $row["idCantidad"];
}else
{
    $item=$row["idProducto"];
}
?>
                        <tr class="gradeA" style="text-align:center;">
                            <td><?php echo $row["idProducto"]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row["idCantidad"]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row["idTipo"]; ?></td>
                        </tr>
<?php
}
?>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th>PRODUCTO</th>
                        <th>CANTIDAD</th>
                        <th>TIPO</th>
                    </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                    </table>
```